# Adding multiple Waypoints to mapbox is not working in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

Trying to add more than 1 waypoint to the route but it just doesn't even build the route :

```
        val builder = NavigationRoute.builder(this@MainActivity) //1
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken()!!) //2
            .origin(originPoint) //3
            .destination(endPoint) //4
        for (wayPoint in wayPoints) {
            builder.addWaypoint(wayPoint)
        }
        builder.build()
```

in my app.gradle I have added al the dependencies needed :

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.1'
```

**Note**

When I add a single waypoint in the route this way :

```
        val builder = NavigationRoute.builder(this@MainActivity) //1
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken()!!) //2
            .origin(originPoint) //3
            .destination(endPoint) //4
            .addWaypoint(wayPoint)
            .build()
```

it works normally .